# bash commands still executing even after exit

Tags: bash, scripting

I am having a problem where my bash script still executes the commands even after the "exit 0" is reached.

```
#!/bin/bash

./command | while IFS= read -r l;

do
    ./command1 | while IFS= read -r m;
        do

            if openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -in junk.txt > junk1.txt -k "${m:9:41}";
            then
                exit 0
            fi
        done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that shell commands that're in pipelines -- like the two `while` loops -- execute in subshells, rather than in the main shell. That means that `exit` in one of those loops exits the subshell, not the parent shell. (And variables defined/changed in the subshell don't affect the parent shell, and...)

There are a couple of ways to get the loops to run in the main shell and avoid this problem. One is to send output to a temp file and then read from that:

```
./command >sometempfile
while IFS= read -r l; do
    ./command >anothertempfile
    while IFS= read -r m; do
        if openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -in junk.txt > junk1.txt -k "${m:9:41}"; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done <anothertempfile
done <sometempfile
```

...but doing that properly involves generating unique tempfile names (`mktemp` is your friend here), deleting them afterward, etc.

The other possibility is to use bash's process substitution feature to redirect the loop's input directly from the other command:

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
    while IFS= read -r m; do
        if openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -in junk.txt > junk1.txt -k "${m:9:41}"; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done < <(./command)
done < <(./command)
```

Using process substitution like this is a lot like a pipeline, except that you control what's in a subprocess and what isn't. Also, this is a bash-only feature. It is not available in other shells, or even in bash when it's invoked as `sh` or anything other than `bash`. So use an explicit bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) and don't override it by running the script with `sh`.

Comment: I usually end a `while` with `done || exit ${?}`; Every cycle will return `0`, so I keep track only of errors. Usually, for ended jobs I use a "boolean" var; I hope this could help some way [: